# Embedding of Frobenius group as a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a Frobenius group with $G=FH$ where $H$ is the complement of the Frobenius kernel $F$.

If $G$ is a normal subgroup of $\Gamma$ then we can see that $G=H^{\Gamma}$.

Conversely, Let $K$ be any subgroup of $\Gamma$. Is there any nontrivial condition which give us $K^{\Gamma}$ is a Frobenius group? For example, is it enough to say that $$K^g\cap N_{\Gamma}(K)=1 \ \forall \,g\notin N_{\Gamma}(K) $$ ?

Comment: No that condition is not enough. It is satisfied for example by a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_5$ or, more generally, by a Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(2,p^k)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks for counter example. Can you see a "nice" conditon ?